# Is there a way to declare variables/read data in Firebase Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to write secured rules for my Firebase realtime database.

I have a list of UIDs who are assigned to a Restaurant ID.

Is there a way of reading the data inside Firebase Rules ? Or declare a variable there as a copy of the assigned UIDs list?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You can read data from database in security rules using [`root`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#referencing_data_in_other_paths) keyword.

Comment: @Dharmaraj that was exactly what I was looking for :D ... tnx